# Django mod_wsgi Apache error 403 Forbidden on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

Django mod_wsgi on Apache application **works fine in Ubuntu 20.04 and previous versions** with the configuration mentioned below,
but when I do the same configuration in Ubuntu 22.04 it gets **403 Forbidden error**. and **Permission denied: mod_wsgi** in the error log.

I tried changing permission on all files it's doesn't work,

Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <Directory /home/ubuntu/mydjango/mydjango>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        alias /static /home/ubuntu/mydjango/static
        <Directory /home/ubuntu/mydjango/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess myapp python-home=/home/ubuntu/mydjango/venv python-path=/home/ubuntu/mydjango
        WSGIProcessGroup myapp
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/mydjango/mydjango/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache Error Log:

```
Current thread 0x00007fb606719780 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
[Sun Jun 05 05:59:07.594727 2022] [wsgi:warn] [pid 37044:tid 140419768883072] (13)Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=37044): Unable to stat Python home /home/ubuntu/mydjango/venv. Python interpreter may not be able to be initialized correctly. Verify the supplied path and access permissions for whole of the path.
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = '/home/ubuntu/mydjango/venv'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = '/home/ubuntu/mydjango/venv'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/home/ubuntu/mydjango/venv'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = '/home/ubuntu/mydjango/venv'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/home/ubuntu/mydjango/venv'
  sys.path = [
    '/home/ubuntu/mydjango/venv/lib/python310.zip',
    '/home/ubuntu/mydjango/venv/lib/python3.10',
    '/home/ubuntu/mydjango/venv/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

Comment: Have you recreated the venv after upgrading the system? If you use the python in `/home/ubuntu/mydjango/venv` environment can you import the `encodings` module manually?

Comment: It a fresh ubuntu 22 install on virtual box, the same setup in made in ubuntu 20 it's working fine but not in ubuntu 22

Comment: when I start with ```python manage.py runserver``` on the venv it's running good, it's only happening on the apache2 mod_wsgi in ubuntu 22

Comment: Yes, I was able to reproduce the problem, its a permission issue with `/home/ubuntu`, see my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default Apache2 run as `www-data` user that does not have permission (read/execute) to home directories. So you should set the correct permissions also on the home directory:

```
sudo chmod 755 /home/ubuntu
```

Or you can put the project into e.g. `/var/www` that is readable/executable by 'others' by default, so Apache2 can run the project from there.

Comment: Thanks, Your answer is working, 
I have another question I didn't give permission to the home directory in ubuntu 20 how does it's working

Comment: They made the home directory private by default in [Ubuntu 21.04](https://ubuntu.com/blog/private-home-directories-for-ubuntu-21-04).

Comment: Took me 48hrs to find this answer. Thank you so much @Dauros

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.  But now, I got new errors.  LOL.  Still +1 since it fixed one issue.